# One mac can file share to another, but not to a 3rd

Tags: finder, network, mount, smb

This is tricky to articulate so I couldn't really find anything in searching.  Here is my situation.

Home network includes 3 macs:

1. 2018 MBP (mine) running High Sierra
2. 2012 Mac Mini (wife's) running Sierra
3. 2011 Mac Mini (household file server) running Sierra.

File sharing is enabled on all 3 machines, both SMB and AFP.

Mac 1 can see and mount the volumes of both other macs without issue.
Mac 2 can see and mount the volumes of both other macs without issue.
Mac 3 cannot connect to or mount the volumes of Mac 2 through Finder, only through the Connect to Server dialog using smb://MacName._smb._tcp.local *or* afp://MacName.local.  In both cases it can then see and mount the volumes of Mac 2 without issue.

If I reboot Mac 2, it will sometimes work normally for a while, sharing from Finder as expected.  But not always, and never permanently.

If I click on Connect As... for Mac 2 from Mac 3, nothing happens.  No prompt, no dialog, nothing.  Finder simply shows it as "not connected".

I have tried disabling SMB on all machines with no change (and I understand that High Sierra and beyond requires SMB now anyway).

Why can't Mac 3 mount the shares of Mac 2 normally from Finder?  This is the only combination that is problematic.

Comment: By "see and mount" do you mean in a Finder window that the Mac appears and selecting it will allow you to select the drive/share to mount? Do you assign IP addresses manually or through the router's DHCP? Have you tried to mount via an IP address rather than a name? Have you removed the entries in the Keychain Utility associated with the servers that do not mount reliably?

Comment: Yes I mean simply selecting the share in the sidebar and choosing the volume to mount. IPs are via DHCP. Mounting via IP or name both work equally fine through the Connect To Server dialog, I just can't access from the normal Finder sidebar.  I have not tried anything with Keychain... good idea and worth a shot.

Comment: FYI I deleted all entries related to Mac 2 from Mac 3's keychain, but Mac 2 is still inaccessible via the Finder Sidebar, and Connect As... still just does nothing.

Comment: Try a "cleaner" app like Onyx to delete all the temp files. Also maybe find all the networking, file sharing and the like preference files in ~/Library and /Library and delete them and reboot. Sorry, I'm grasping at straws. I'm running out of ideas, and honestly I have never had much luck with Mac networking. Always found it mildly unreliable and finickly. And I hate to say it Windows networking is SO much better... sigh...

Comment: Thanks I'll have to give it a shot. Mac Networking was always the absolute most bulletproof around, it always "just worked" and all machines would see each other like magic.  Until OSX came along anyway.  Pretty much since then, total crapshoot. But in the System 6 to 9 days... man the Mac was a dream come true. Now it's just another computing platform. Ah the good ol' days...  lol